# PHP driver for NEO4J

Tags: php, neo4j

I upgraded my old Neo4J Application from 3.2.7 to 4.x now and it seems that now my old driver from Everyman (https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) seems not working anymore, I receive this:

```
Uncaught Everyman\Neo4j\Exception: Unable to retrieve server info [404]:
```

Does anybody has experience with this problem? Or maybe a different suggestion how to use PHP on Neo4J 4.x?

I have checked graphaware neo4j-php-client but composer tells me

```
 Package graphaware/neo4j-php-client is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
```

This seems not an alternative then. I am sure there must be another option as PHP isn't such an exot - any hints?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project appears to have been abandoned and it sounds like a code fix would be required to use it with Neo4j 4.x.  The code is in github so that is an option.

If you haven't looked at it yet, maybe check this out

https://neo4j.com/developer/php/

Comment: Aye, from there I grabbed the link to graphaware which led to the abandoned projects. The good news is, I have found an active version: https://github.com/transistive/neo4j-php-client-http-v4.0-support - this seems to work. Thanks for your help!